# Two dataframes with different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resize, columnsorting

This is my code for dataframing for both df1 and df2. I'm trying to merge these df1 and df2.

```
   import pandas as pd
   df1 = pd.read_table("mass2.txt")
   df1.columns =['ID']
   print(df1)
   df2 = pd.read_table("combined.txt",sep=",")
   df2.columns =['Teff','ID']
   print(df2)
   columns_titles = ["ID","Teff"]
   df3=df2.reindex(columns=columns_titles)
   print(df3)
   df4 = df1.merge(df3, on='ID', how='left')
   print(df4)´´´
I need to merge df2 and df1. There are similar IDs in df1 and 
df2 but it's not giving me the respective Teff.
   
I'm getting an output like this:
```

```
                     ID Teff
0 J22154748 + 4954052 NaN
1 J22154748 + 4954052 NaN
2 J22152631 + 4958343 NaN
3 J22154748 + 4954052 NaN
4 J22154748 + 4954052 NaN
... ... ...
1122 AP17515104-3446100 NaN
1123 AP17515104-3446100 NaN
1124 J05062845 + 4112062 NaN
1125 J16142485-3141000 NaN
1126 J16142485-3141000 NaN´´´
```

So, there is nothing in Teff column for similar IDs I have in
df1 and df2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A'])
```

If these are two dataframes as df1 and df2
[image]

[image]

After performing `merge` it becomes

[image]

Comment: I tried that too. It doesn't give me the second column.

Comment: I've edited the answer, you just need to specify the column that you want.

Comment: It is still giving me an empty dataframe. Also, I'm reading the input from a text file.

Comment: If you can share your code, then I might be able to help more.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: I have edited the answer by changing the dfs, and changed the solution.

Comment: I tried this too. It is giving me 284083 rows x 2 columns instead of 1128 rows x 2 columns. If  I try df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left') the second column is Nan .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242789/discussion-between-tron-and-k-ashyap).